# Simple way to parse numbers as strings while sorting with Java streams?

Tags: java, sorting, parsing, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects that contain values stored as strings but are actually numbers and I'm trying to find a way to parse strings to integers within a Java stream to sort them numerically. Here's what I got so far.

```
List<SearchResultObject> returnedValues = doTheSearchMethod();
returnedValues = returnedValues
.stream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(SearchResultObject::getNumber))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As of right now this kind of works, but the problem is that because those numbers are actually strings, it sorts the numbers lexicographically, not numerically. Is there a way to incorporate parsing into the stream? All numbers are padded to be the same size.

```
3356001017053000000000000
3356001017002000000000000
3356001017004000000000000
3356001017026000000000000
5101004003020000000000000
4123000006002510000000000
4758000005010000000000000
```

Comment: What about changing `SearchResultObject.getNumber()` so that it will return a `long` or a `Number` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `comparingLong` and then parse long. the numbers are too large for integers.

```
returnedValues.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(sro->Long.parseLong(sro.getNumber())));
```

Answer (score 0):

For just sorting you don't need stream, just use custom `Comparator` using lambda expression

```
Comparator<SearchResultObject> c = Comparator.comparingLong(s->Long.parseLong(s.getNumber()));
```

And then use `Collections.sort` method

```
Collections.sort(returnedValues,c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Streams API for sorting the list, you can directly use `sort()` method from the List interface. You just need to ensure that you provide a proper `comparator` to the `sort()` method.

As you mentioned, you can directly use:

```
Comparator.comparing(SearchResultObject::getNumber)
```

comparator to compare the strings.

However, as you need the list to be sorted by comparing the Integer/Long, you can use the following:

1. For Integer:

   `list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(s ->Integer.parseInt(s.getNumber())));`
2. For Long:

   `list.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(s ->Long.parseLong(s.getNumber())));`

You can check the output for the following code below:

```
Before sorting
SearchResultObject{number='100'}
SearchResultObject{number='2'}
SearchResultObject{number='10'}
After sorting
SearchResultObject{number='2'}
SearchResultObject{number='10'}
SearchResultObject{number='100'}
```

The above output is based on the assumption the `SearchResultObject` contains a `number` as the field.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify `SearchResultObject` add a method to it converting the `String` to `BigInteger` and use it in your `Comparator`

```
public SearchResultObject {
    ...
    public BigInteger getNumberAsBigInteger() {
        return new BigInteger(this.number);
    }
    ...
}
```

And the invocation is

```
returnedValues.stream()
              .sorted(
                  Comparator.comparing(
                      SearchResultObject::getNumberAsBigInteger
                  )
              )
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

If you can't modify the `SearchResultObject` class, then you'll have to customize your `Comparator` a bit, but nothing too complicated

```
returnedValues.stream()
              .sorted(
                  Comparator.comparing(
                      sro -> new BigInteger(sro.getNumber())
                  )
              )
              .collect(toList());
```